# iFrames and Google Ads not interactive on posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

iFrames and Google Ads (within posts) are no longer interactive on my site, meaning users can no longer click the ads. Ads outside of the post area (sidebar for example) are perfectly fine though.

I have not changed anything in the post template, or updated any templates so I'm not sure why I have this issue now.

Not sure what to post to give as an example, so here's an example of a post with this issue. I should say, that **the ads are only visible on mobile within the posts**.

http://www.thisisardee.ie/2016/05/12/romance-brew-ardee-karen/

**HEADER:** http://pastebin.com/Ne6yuf4a

**SINGLE POST TEMPLATE:** http://pastebin.com/9H0qcc9d

**SIDEBAR TEMPLATE:** http://pastebin.com/ym0NXWCQ

Could it be a CSS issue?

Any help would be massively appreciated. This is affecting potential revenue from the site.

Thanks.

EDIT: From looking further. The issue only appears to be affecting mobile users. So, given that the in-content adverts only become active on mobile, also. It could be to do with ads. Still no idea of a fix though.

Comment: you tagged as php; visiting your site won't help us if this is a php-related issue. If it is, you need to post your code for it, and all related/relevant code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cheers for the heads up. Added the page templates.

Comment: thanks Kelvin, however those are expiring links (in 29 days). You need to create new links and not make them expire.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

One method for resolving issues like this is to open Chrome (or any other browser) Developer Tools and try to select the non-working ad. In this particular case, you will notice that there is another HTML element on top, namely the `div` element with classes `sidebar sidebar-popular`.

Solutions are many, one simple solution is just to drop the z-index of the element with CSS:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-popular {
    z-index: -1;
}
```